# Iterate over dataframe names in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, dataframes.jl

I am trying to generate `n` dataframes using a loop, where each dataframe has one column with `i` rows populated with random numbers where `i=1:n`. So far, none of the following iterating methods work for iterating over dataframe names in order to generate them:

```
n = 5;
for i = 1:n 
    "df_$i" = DataFrame(rand($i), :auto)
end
```

or

```
n = 5;
for i = 1:n 
    "df_$(i)" = DataFrame(rand($i), :auto)
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a `Vector{DataFrame}` would be better? Most likely you would like to manipulate these dataframes together later and the loop code would be easier.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your answer. This has also been suggested by Bogumil. i will try and see if this can be applied in my actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> [DataFrame("col$i" => rand(i)) for i in 1:3]
3-element Vector{DataFrame}:
 1×1 DataFrame
 Row │ col1
     │ Float64
─────┼──────────
   1 │ 0.368821
 2×1 DataFrame
 Row │ col2
     │ Float64
─────┼──────────
   1 │ 0.757023
   2 │ 0.201711
 3×1 DataFrame
 Row │ col3
     │ Float64
─────┼──────────
   1 │ 0.702651
   2 │ 0.256179
   3 │ 0.560374
```

(I additionally showed you how to dynamically generate the name of the column in each data frame)

Comment: Thanks Bogumil for your answer. I will try to see if you answer which involves generating a Vector{DataFrame} (as was also suggested by Dan) works in my case. What I am eventually trying to do is quite complex, but is hindered as of now with the inability to loop over dataframe names. 
I have a function which "cleans" and "generates" a new dataframe. In doing so, I need to create/work with multiple intermediate dataframes for `j` time periods (t) and `n` groups (g) -- for which i want to loop over t and g to create df_t1_g1 ... df_tj_g1, ...,  df_t1_gn, ... df_tj_gn and then work with them.

Comment: you can use a `Dict` mapping names as keys to data frames as values instead.